# Way to have a TCP/UDP echo on range of ports

Tags: firewall, testing

Is there some quick command or thing I can do to make system basically [echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Protocol) or [chargen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Generator_Protocol) on a large range tcp or udp ports?

I am trying to play around with and learn more about nftables, and one thing that make this a lot easier is if I had some kind of simple daemon I could start that would more or less just reply to anything, or return a stream of test data on all the ports that I am trying to verify are working.

Comment: You could always DNAT a whole range of ports to one single port where a server is listening?